# How to shorten Firebase storage download retrying period on Network Error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have basic working code for downloading file from Firebase storage.

```
String key = "gs://.../test.jpg";
File file = new File(getCacheDir() + File.separator + "test.jpg");

FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference gsRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(key);

gsRef.getFile(file)
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
{
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
    {
        Log.d("APP", "onSuccess");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception)
    {
        Log.d("APP", "onFailure: ", exception);
    }
});
```

However, if above code is executed while device is not connected to Internet it takes almost 10 minutes before `onFailure` event is finally triggered. In the meantime log is filling up with repeated retries:

```
02-27 21:41:07.203 12954-13288/com.example.test E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ <<Network Error>> ]
02-27 21:41:08.244 12954-13288/com.example.test W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
02-27 21:41:08.294 12954-13288/com.example.test E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ <<Network Error>> ]
02-27 21:41:09.405 12954-13288/com.example.test W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
02-27 21:41:09.485 12954-13288/com.example.test E/StorageUtil: error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ <<Network Error>> ]
```

Is there a way I can shorten (customize) retry period and trigger `onFailure` event sooner?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, you can configure the timeout for uploads, downloads, and other operations using the `setMaximum{OPERATION}RetryTimeMillis()` methods:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
storage.setMaxDownloadRetryTimeMillis(60000);  // wait 1 min for downloads
storage.setMaxOperationRetryTimeMillis(10000);  // wait 10s for normal ops
storage.setMaxUploadRetryTimeMillis(120000);  // wait 2 mins for uploads
```

See [the reference docs for more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html#setMaxDownloadRetryTimeMillis(long)),