# Firebase storage no internet connection callback

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am loading some data from firebase storage when the app begins, I am setting 'onSuccessListener' and 'onFailureListener' to hide the progress bar when loading completes.
The issue is : when I try the app offline, I receive no callbacks at all. I tried 'onCompleteListener' but it wasn't called, too
It gives me this messages in console :

```
W/ManagedChannelImpl: [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
W/Firestore: (21.4.1) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:420)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.resolveInternal(DnsNameResolver.java:256)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:157)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:640)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:388)
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.resolveInternal(DnsNameResolver.java:256) 
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:213) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
        at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154) 
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:640) 
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAll(DnsNameResolver.java:388) 
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.resolveInternal(DnsNameResolver.java:256) 
        at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:213) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
    }
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

and then these messeges as long as the app is running :

```
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
W/ExponenentialBackoff: network unavailable, sleeping.
.
.
.
```

After waiting for so long, It finally gives an error and fires the 'failure listener' :

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    The operation retry limit has been exceeded.
     Code: -13030 HttpResult: -2
E/StorageException: Could not open resulting stream.
    java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream.
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.createDownloadStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:145)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:36)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:167)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:164)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.ensureStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:325)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:262)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:175)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    The operation retry limit has been exceeded.
     Code: -13030 HttpResult: -2
E/StorageException: Could not open resulting stream.
    java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream.
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.createDownloadStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:145)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:36)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:167)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:164)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.ensureStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:325)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:262)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:175)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/Warning: Maybe internet or authentication issues
    com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: The operation retry limit has been exceeded.
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.snapStateImpl(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:229)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.snapStateImpl(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:35)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.snapState(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:343)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.TaskListenerImpl.onInternalStateChanged(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:85)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.tryChangeState(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:390)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.tryChangeState(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:426)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:201)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream.
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.createDownloadStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:145)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:36)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:167)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:164)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.ensureStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:325)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$StreamProgressWrapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:262)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:175)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I want to receive a callback when this happens as soon as possible.

Comment: Attach your errors in correct way. Without internet how do you want to connect to Firebase?

Comment: I want firebase to try to bring the data and if i couldn't It shouldn't keep trying, just inform me that it couldn't

Comment: See my answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Comment: I don't really understand how it's related to my question.

Comment: Nore that I am using firebase storage, I tried 'failure', 'cancel', 'complete' listeners but none was called

Comment: Make your question more clear

Comment: Ok, here is what I am tryin to do : I am reading data from firebase storage, on completing, i hide the progress bar whether I succeeded or failed and the user can keep using the app in both cases, it works fine when online, but when offline, I recieve no callbacks at all, firebase simply keeps retrying to fetch the data, It doesn' stop until after a very long time. now what I want is this : try to get the data, If you couldn't bring it due to internet unavailabilty, don't retry just tell me. How do i receive this callback ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do receive a failure callback, but with the reason `ERROR_RETRY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED`. Seems like FirebaseStorage does not check if it has internet connection and still tries to start a task.
Don't you wanna check if there is internet connection before starting an upload/download task by yourself?

```
    public static boolean isOnline() {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 8.8.8.8");
            int     exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
            return (exitValue == 0);
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        return false;
    }
```

**Edit:**

Usually you want to keep this feature on with retrying loading your data. Imagine a situation when your user have an internet connection, but its a bit slow or inconsistent and `FirebaseStorage` will manage to start download task with a second or third attempt.

There is only one option to affect `FirebaseStorage` retry mechanism and it is described here: [How to shorten Firebase storage download retrying period on Network Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495696/how-to-shorten-firebase-storage-download-retrying-period-on-network-error)

 Or you can do what I already suggested, to first check if the user has internet connection and only then start the task:

```
void yourMethod(...) {
   if (!isOnline) {
       //hiding progress bar
       //and fallback, maybe Toast to inform the user about the issue with internet connection
       return;
   }
   // start your download task
}
```

Comment: I am receiving this error 'ERROR_RETRY_LIMIT_EXCEEDED' after a very long time, I want firebase storage to inform me that it couldn't load the data and not retry loading it again

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. I just want to limit retries for this one data query as I am loading this data in splash activity, I don't want user to wait too long until app starts